# What is the purpose of "Dynamic Web Module"? And how does tomcat detect the project while Doing Add resource?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I have been working in a project with a lot of manual work, So I am in dire need to understand the basics of few behind the scenes.
I know, If I uncheck the "Dynamic Web Module" box in project facet, I will not be able to Add my web project as an "Resource" to my Tomcat Server(8.0).

But when it is checked, what tomcat does in order to find the that project? 
Is any jar/war/ear is created automatically, may be while build, which tomcat adds as the resource? if Yes, where is it located?

Or Tomcat Assumes it to be a Web project and copy all the files in webapps directory?

Comment: There is a tomcat server location where tomcat deploys the applications...it can be found by clicking on the server in the servers view and go to server locations to find the location

Comment: that is where the project will be deployed, I need to know what role does the **dynamic web module** have in making tomcat inside eclipse detect that a certain project is a web project and can be added as a 'resource'.

Comment: i think you have already answered the question..dynamic web project is required for tomcat to understand it...